# Cocoa Podでインストール出来ない

Tags: swift, cocoapods

Cocoa podを入れて早速目的のOSSをインストールしようとしましたが下記エラーのためできません。

エラー

```html
Analyzing dependencies
[!] Unable to satisfy the following requirements:

- `Timepiece (~> 0.4.0)` required by `Podfile`
```

Cocoa podはrbenvで作成したバージョン2.2.2のrubyを使って入れました。
Podfileは下記のようになっています。

```html
platform :ios, '7.1'
pod "Timepiece", "~> 0.4.0"
```

解決方法を教えて下さい。よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!
target 'hoge' do
  pod "Timepiece", "~> 0.4.0"
end
```

に変えたところうまくいきました。